# replacing first link of a text "awk equivalent of sed command"

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, osx, string

I wanted to replace the first line of a text with sed it should be like

```
sed -i.bak "1 s/^.*$/"CompoundState\tMethod\tApproach\tS^2\tEnergy\tPath"/" awk.xls
```

but I also need to run it on OSX but it doesn't support "\t" tab space
is there an awk equivalent?

Comment: How about: `'1 s/^.*$/CompoundState\tMethod\tApproach\tS^2\tEnergy\tPath/'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Some shells, including bash, allow you to type any literal character (e.g. Ctrl-I for Tab, Ctrl-M for Return) by prefixing it with Ctrl-V, so you could type `Ctrl-V Ctrl-I` instead of `\t` wherever it appears in your sed one-liner.